# Indenting multiple apex code and pages

Tags: code

Is there any new tool to do code indentation for multiple Apex classes and vf pages at a single stroke?

Answer (score 6):

[Illuminated Cloud](http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/)'s integrated [formatter](http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/home/formatter) can reformat multiple Apex classes/triggers, Visualforce pages/components, and XML metadata files with a single keystroke and is highly configurable (>100 options for the Apex formatter).